# How to generalize a for loop for all alfanumerical characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

*I want to preface this by saying that I'm fully aware that you can simplify this whole endeavor by avoiding the loop in the first place, but this is a longer project, so let's please just assume the original loop has to stay.*

I created a loop that turns a string into a list at the empty space between words.

```
string= "This my string"
my_list = []
word = ""

for char in string:
    if char != " ":
        word += char
        if char is string[-1]:
            my_list.append(word)
    else:
        my_list.append(word)
        word = ""
```

The output therefore is:

`['This', 'is', 'my', 'string.']`

Now I would like to add a placeholder to the `if char != " "`, so I can later input any alphanumeric character to split the string at. So if I input `i` into this placeholder variable, the split would look like this:

`['Th', 's my str', 'ng.']`

I've attempted doing so with `%s`, but can't get it to work.

So how can I change/add to this loop to have a placeholder included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you are looking for?

```
string= "This my string"
my_list = []
word = ""
character = " " # change for the char you want to split on

for char in string:
    if char != character:
        word += char
        if char is string[-1]:
            my_list.append(word)
    else:
        my_list.append(word)
        word = ""
```

It may be simpler to just use `string.split(" ")` or `string.split(character)` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check if `char is string[-1]` every iteration just append word at the end after the loop. Also `string` overwrites the builtin `string` name.

As for changing the delimiter just change it at the beginning of the program

```
my_string = "This my string"
my_list = []
word = ""
delimiter = "i"

for char in my_string:
    if char != delimiter:
        word += char
    else:
        my_list.append(word)
my_list.append(word)
```

Result:

```
['Th', 's my str', 'ng']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split() function to split strings.
For case I, you can use `string.split(" ")`
For case II, you can use `string.split("i")`

Or you can add any character inside split(), like: `string.split(char)`